# How to refactor an if else if with previous state when using useState Hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 `details` tag, each has a control to toggle it on/off. Code snippet [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-merkle-g121b?file=/src/App.js). Clicking Control A should toggle on/off page A, clicking Control B should toggle on/off page B.

I did it with an `if else if` plus 2 `useState`, this would not be feasible when there are multiple `details`. How can I refactor the code such that maybe the `if else if` can be avoided and it detects which Control I click in a cleverer way?

Page.js

```
const Page = ({ name, isOpen, setIsOpen }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <details
        open={isOpen}
        onToggle={(e) => {
          setIsOpen(e.target.open);
        }}
      >
        <summary>Page {name} title</summary>
        <div>Page {name} contents</div>
      </details>
    </>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

Control.js

```
const Control = ({ toggle }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <a onClick={() => toggle("A")} href="#/">
        Control A
      </a>
      <br />
      <a onClick={() => toggle("B")} href="#/">
        Control B
      </a>
    </>
  );
};
```

App.js

```
export default function App() {
  const [isOpenA, setIsOpenA] = useState(false);
  const [isOpenB, setIsOpenB] = useState(false);

  const toggle = (name) => {
    if (name === "A") {
      setIsOpenA((prevState) => !prevState);
    } else if (name === "B") {
      setIsOpenB((prevState) => !prevState);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Control toggle={toggle} />
      <Page name={"A"} isOpen={isOpenA} setIsOpen={setIsOpenA} />
      <Page name={"B"} isOpen={isOpenB} setIsOpen={setIsOpenB} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array to represent open ones

`const [openPages, setOpenPages]  = useState([])`

And to toggle filter the array

```
const toggle = (name) => {
    if(openPages.includes(name)){
        setOpenPages(openPages.filter(o=>o!=name))
    }else{
         setOpenPages(pages=>{ return [...pages,name]}
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a working example please?

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use an object as a map for your toggles as in something like:

```
const [isOpen, _setIsOpen] = useState({});

const setIsOpen = (pageName,value) => _setIsOpen({
 ...isOpen,
 [pageName]: value
});

const toggle = (name) => setIsOpen(name, !isOpen[name]);
```

and then in the template part:

```
<Page name={"A"} isOpen={isOpen["A"]} setIsOpen={toggle("A")} />
```

In this way you can have as many toggles you want and use them in any way you want

I think this would be quite cleaner, also you should put the various page names in an array and iterate over them as in

```
const pageNames = ["A","B"];

{
 pageNames.map( name => 
             <Page name={name} isOpen={isOpen[name]} setIsOpen={toggle(name)} />)
}
```

At least that's how I would go about it

Comment: since there is not a working example I could not run my code, but it should be alright, if something does not work properly (because of a syntax error or similar things) I apologise, but anyways the basic concept of my solution should be quite clear :)

Comment: Also note that `undefined` in js is falsy so if you start with an empty object all your toggles will be considered as false, you can initialise them anyways if you want (using the pageNames array)

Comment: Thanks, `setIsOpen('A', true)` makes the control only toggle on, not off.

Comment: sorry I misunderstood what you wanted there, but ok, instead of that you can simply call toggle, I've edited my answer :)

Comment: The toggle is now an infinite on/off loop.

Answer (score 0):

Adithya's answer worked for me.

For future reference, I put the full working code here. The `onToggle` attribute in `Page.js` is not needed. All required is passing correct `true/false` to `open={isOpen}` in `Page.js`.

App.js:

```
export default function App() {
  const [openPages, setOpenPages] = useState([]);

  const toggle = (name) => {
    if (openPages.includes(name)) {
      setOpenPages(openPages.filter((o) => o !== name));
    } else {
      setOpenPages((pages) => {
        return [...pages, name];
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Control toggle={toggle} />
      <Page name={"A"} isOpen={openPages.includes("A")} />
      <Page name={"B"} isOpen={openPages.includes("B")} />
      <Page name={"C"} isOpen={openPages.includes("C")} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Page.js

```
const Page = ({ name, isOpen }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <details open={isOpen}>
        <summary>Page {name} title</summary>
        <div>Page {name} contents</div>
      </details>
    </>
  );
};
```

Control.js remains the same.